# If while press and holding grabbed key, other keys are also "grabbed"

Tags: x11, xlib, xorg, xcb

I have grabbed a key with `XGrabKey`:

```
int mods = 0;
bool ownerevents = true;
XGrabKey(display, MY_KEYCODE, mods, rootwin, ownerevents, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
```

It succesfully grabs the key. In my example `MY_KEYCODE` is for that of key `b`. So now my event loop is picking up only if I press the `b` key. HOWEVER if I hold down the `b` key and then press other keys, those are also getting reported to my event loop and are also being blocked, so "grabbed" temporarily. I thought to try `XAllowEvents` in the `KeyPressed` part, but it is not working.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get other keys, while my grabbed key is held, to succesfully pass through ungrabbed?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Once the grabbed key is pressed, the entire keyboard is grabbed until the key is released. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @n.m. for the reading and comment! How do the apps work where they send another key when I press one key. Like if I press "e" it should send "a". Do they send it on `KeyRelease`?

Comment: This is normally done with remapping a key.

Comment: Ooo, thanks @n.m. !

Comment: @n.m. may you please post these two comments as solution so I can accept it. I like to show my appreciation to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do what your want. Once the grabbed key is pressed, the entire keyboard is grabbed until the key is released.

If you want programmatically globally replace a keysym bound to a key, this is normally done with key remapping. See `XChangeKeyboardMapping` and `XkbChangeMap`.

If you just want remap a key permanently and don't care how it's done, you probably want to write/modify a config file and not bother with programming at all. See `xmodmap` and `xkbcomp`.